# How can I enable wifi on my Ubuntu 11.10 xps l702x?

Tags: 11.10, wireless, dell

Network configuration:

'Wireless is disabled by hardware switch'
'Enable wireless' is disabled and I can not enable it

When I press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> - no results. Wifi is not fires on a pad.

Comment: Well... stating the obvious, is your wireless disabled by the hardware switch? Press the wireless  button on your computer and find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same experience. I disabled wireless (in Ubuntu's network manager) and then was unable to re-enable it. Fn+F2 doesn't do anything inside Ubuntu; I needed to reboot Windows to re-enable wireless, where Fn+F2 behaved as expected.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, this fixed it for me:

```
sudo modprobe iwlagn power_level=5
sudo modprobe btusb reset=1
sudo rfkill unblock all
```

Then disable and re-enable wifi with fn+f2.
After that, fn+f2 works, bluetooth can be disabled without disabling wifi, and wifi can be re-enabled after it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition (i.e. Ubuntu pre-installed). A workaround was to reboot, but it only helped when I first pressed <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> again (so that it *should* work) and then re-booted.

Answer (score 0):

The Intel wireless driver module appears to have been renamed. Try replacing `iwlagn` with `iwlwifi` like so:

```
sudo modprobe iwlagn power_level=5
```